# FineUploader onProgress() callback does not work for Android

Tags: javascript, web-applications, fine-uploader

onProgress() callback of Fine Uploader does not work in Android devices. Here is my code:

```
onProgress: function(id, fileName, loaded, total)
{
    //alert('debug'); this alert shows after download is completer
    if (loaded < total) {
        progress = '"' + fileName + '" uploaded ' + Math.round(loaded / total*100) +'%';                                                              
        $('#progress').html(progress);
    }
    else {
        $('#progress').html('saving');
    }
}
```

onProgress() is called after uploading has finished. What can be problem and how to fix it?
In [official docs](http://docs.fineuploader.com/api/callbacks.html) it says: `onProgress(String id, String name, int uploadedBytes, int totalBytes) - called during the upload, as it progresses. Only used by the XHR/ajax uploader.`

Comment: What version of android?

Comment: @RayNicholus Android 4.0.4

Comment: Does this happen for all files, or just small ones?

Comment: @RayNicholus I have tested for 4 MB. My connection is slow enough to notice it, other callbacks are working well.

Comment: @RayNicholus here I have posted my working code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17880719/fineuploaderbasic-calling-cancelall

Comment: Is this working on other browsers, such as desktop chrome?  If it is, there may be an issue specific to Android that Fine Uploader may need to work around.  If you are having the same problem in other browsers, then the issue is likely with your code.  Either way l'll have to take a closer look on Monday.

Comment: @RayNicholus I have installed Firefox in my Android device. It works. Also it even works on native browser of Android 2.X. So I think this problem is specific to some Android devices.

Comment: The only browser on Android that is officially supported (by Fine Uploader) at this time is the stock browser.

Answer (score 3):

After some digging around I determined that -- as of writing this -- Android 4.0.4's stock browser does **not** fully support the [XMLHttpRequest specification](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/xhr/raw-file/tip/Overview.html/). Specifically, the XMLHttpRequest object does not fire [ProgressEvents](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/progress/raw-file/tip/Overview.html) which are essential to determining the progress of the currently uploading file.

I've attempted to bind event handlers to the `onprogress` event a variety of ways, and even followed the [Mozilla Developer Network article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17901630/fineuploader-onprogress-callback-does-not-work-for-android?noredirect=1#17901630), but to no avail.

The `onprogress` event is correctly fired on Chrome for Android.

I've filed [an issue in our tracker here](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/931). Hopefully a workaround is found, or Google et al. fix this issue.

If you have any suggestions for workarounds, please, feel free to share