# FineUploader OnProgress Event Not Firing in IE

Tags: progress-bar, fine-uploader

I've found similar questions on [fineuploader's github page](https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues/217) and here on [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17901630/fineuploader-onprogress-callback-does-not-work-for-android), but none seem to fully address my issue.

Some background: I have an AngularJS application using FineUploader v4.0.1. Instead of using the UI's progress bars, I have my own Bootstrap-based bar that's triggered and updated by the OnProgress() event. Something like this...

```
onProgress: function(id, fileName, loaded, total) {     
    if (total > 0) {
        $scope.individualFileProgressList[id] = Math.round(loaded / total * 100);
        $scope.updateTotalFileProgress();
    }
}
```

...where updateTotalFileProgress() adjusts the bar.

It works well in every browser I've tested (Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Edge), but not in IE (11 and earlier). I did some testing and found that the OnProgress() event never fires, which was confirmed when reading the github issue posted above.

With that being said, what are the options for anyone who wants to use their own progress bar implementation? Is there an IE-friendly alternative to OnProgress()? Have there been any updates to FineUploader since v4.0.1 that might help me (didn't see anything in the changelogs)? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`onProgress` *will* fire in IE10 and 11. If you are seeing issues, I'd suggest updating to a current version of Fine Uploader. Version 4 is several years old at the moment. Version 5.6 was just released. In browsers older than IE10, there is no way to determine upload progress client-side.